# Properties of transitors used as diodes

Tags: transistors, analog, diodes

Consider the NPN BJT. Normally, if you want to use it as a diode, you short base to collector and treat the emitter as the cathode. But in principle, you could also use the base emitter junction by itself (collector floating), or even the base collector junction (emitter floating). I guess you could even tie the emitter and base together and treat the collector as the cathode. What would the properties be of these diodes? Anything that might be useful in special circumstances?

Answer (score 3):

If you follow [BJT modelling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipolar_junction_transistor#Theory_and_modeling), then you can conclude these facts

- *Emitter* is doped highest but has considerable bigger area than *base* and lesser than *collector*
- *Base* is doped considerable more than *collector* but less than *emitter* and is having least area
- *Collector* is doped least and has maximum area among *all three*.

Now this will lead to Band diagram as shown below.

[image: Band diagram]

Thus for considerable amount of *drift* & *diffusion* currents as per study from  **Energy levels** , Base and collector must be shorted to make a **P-type** node of Diode and Emitter is heavily doped already hence it will make **N-type** node of Diode

**NOTE : *I might be not able to explain well , but I hope this facts come useful to understand***

---

added later on

### Why to short *Base-Collector* , Instead of *Base-Emitter*

Lets say following abbrevations for sake of explanation
BE: Base Emitter Junction
CB: Base Collector Junction

Consider the **BE** as single entity,Now since *emitter* is doped more heavy compared to *base* **BE** junction will act as *N-Type* element, since u are left with *collector* which is already *N-Type* element , Thus it will result in bad diode.
Now on other hand for **CB** as single entity, *base* is more heavy doped compared to *collector*, Hence **CB** will act as *P-Type* element, you are left with **emitter** which is already comparative doped as *N-Type* element. Thus this can result in well functional Diode.

---

More ....

$$
I_E = I_B +\ I_C \\
I_C = \beta  I_B \\
I_C = \alpha I_E \\
I_E = (\beta +\ 1)I_B \\
I_C=I_s e^{\left(\frac{V_{BE}}{V_T}\right)} \\
\text{Normal values of}~\beta = 99 ~ \& ~ \alpha = 0.01\\
I_E \approx I_C \approx \text{few hundreds}~mA \\
I_B \approx \text{few}~\mu A
$$
On study of above equations, we can have few conclusions

- *emitter* & *collector* contribute major amount of currents. compared to *base*
- *base* has to be in picture as its connecting link for *collector* & *emitter*

***PS: this [lab document](http://home.comcast.net/~mercerd/MobileStudioProject/Activity_2_bjt_diode.pdf) has some good insights***

Comment: I like the answer but I would welcome a better explanation why base and collector actually "have to" be shorted. Why not just use base and emitter? Maybe someone else can contribute some more details.

Comment: @Rev1.0 I think the later added explanation can help..

Comment: Maybe my question wasn't clear. That connecting BC still results in a p-region is understandable, there are simply more positive carriers in the base than negative in the collector region. My actual question was more: Why not ignore the collector? E-B should make a better diode than E-BC. That was essentially also part of the original question.

Comment: @JigarGandhi I am very interesting about this subject since this technick used very often inside of ICs. So please try again and edit.

Comment: i am not able to get exact reason i feel.. hope someone gets exact reason.